# chrome.storage.sync.set value is not available in content script using react chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

This is my `FormComponent.tsx` which used to store input key in local storage but storage key isn't pushed in localstorage I am using `chrome.storage.sync.set`

```
import React,{useState,useEffect,useRef,useCallback} from "react";


export default function FormComponent() {
    
    const [apikey, setApikey] = useState('');
    
    const [isSending, setIsSending] = useState(false)
    
    const isMounted = useRef(true)
  
    // set isMounted to false when we unmount the component
    useEffect(() => {
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) {
            const currentTabID = tabs.length === 0 ? 0 : tabs[0].id!;
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(currentTabID, { access: true },response => {
                setIsSending(response);        
            });
          });        
    }, [])
  
    const sendRequest = useCallback(async () => {
      // don't send again while we are sending
      if (isSending) return
      // update state
      setIsSending(true)
      // send the actual request            
      // api request goes here 
      // once the request is sent, update state again
      if (isMounted.current) // only update if we are still mounted
        setIsSending(false)
    }, [isSending]) // update the callback if the state changes
  
  
    const submitForm = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
      // Preventing the page from reloading
      event.preventDefault();  

      chrome.storage.sync.set({'some_os_key': apikey}, function() {
        sendRequest();
      });         
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
            <div className="mb-6">
                <label htmlFor="success" className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-green-700 dark:text-green-500">Your apikey</label>
                <input 
                value={apikey}
                onChange={(e) => setApikey(e.target.value)}
                type="text"
                 id="success" 
                 className="bg-green-50 border border-green-500 text-green-900 dark:text-green-400 placeholder-green-700 dark:placeholder-green-500 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-green-500" placeholder="apikey goes here.."/>
            </div>
            <div className="rounded-md shadow">
                <button 
                className="w-full flex items-center justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-sky-500 px-5 py-1 text-sm font-medium text-white hover:bg-sky-600"> Validate Key</button>
            </div>                
            </form>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

and my `feature.ts` which used to get storage key

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.access === true) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(["some_so_key"], (result) => {
      console.log(`localstorage apikey goes here = ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
    });

    //condition goes here 
    return true;
  }
});
```

Problem is `some_so_key` is not available in Application local storage. How can i resolve this.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It means the value is not there. Debug your code and look at the timing specifically: apparently the content script runs before the value is set. It can happen if it's declared in manifest.json which means it runs automatically whenever a page loads.

Comment: yes @wOxxOm , how can i prevent and store key before content script, I have tried chrome.tabs.query within submitForm though; but realtime local.storage not available in content script

Comment: You can use chrome.storage.onChanged in the content script instead of messages.

Comment: @wOxxOm, Thanks for your information, but its still not working with chrome.storage.onchanged as i have set chrome.storage.sync.set from react and wantted to get key value in content script in my case feature.ts is my content script

Comment: Well, it means the content script runs before the code that sets the value. It probably means the logic of your code is incorrect, so you need to rethink it.